# Linker command failed with exit code 1 In Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, linker-errors

I'm writing C program in Xcode, and I got this problem:

```
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea to solve it?

Note: I've just update my OS to Mountain Lion yesterday.

Comment: Ideas to solve it: 1) if it tells you which symbol is duplicated, find out why there are multiple definitions. 2) if it doesn't, or you can't figure it out, post the code and the compiler and link commands

Answer (score 2):

A common error is to *define* a symbol in a header when you wanted to *declare* it:

When you for instance declare a global variable and forget the `extern` or you define an inline function and forget the `inline`. In these cases the compiler emits the symbol in each compile unit that includes this header and you end up with multiple definitions of a symbol.

Anyway you should just look for the symbol in question.