# "ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd'" in YAML file GFortran

Tags: xcode, gfortran

I am trying to run basing *Hello, World!* Fortran code, but I get this error:

> ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64 
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I am using

- [macOS v13.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura) (22C65)
- Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18)
- GCC version 12

I have tried

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

but no luck.

Comment: Re *"I am using ... GCC"*: OK, it does seem to be GCC. The signature for [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) may or may not be *"[clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080846/why-do-i-get-clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1)"*. But macOS + executable `gcc` usually means [it is the Clang compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840601/how-can-i-ignore-an-error-when-using-gcc-compile-option-werror#comment130977909_38840601), not GCC.

Comment: (The GCC signature may be something like *"collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"* (as here).)

Answer (score 1):

The issue stemmed from an architecture conflict - specifically, I had installed GCC via homebrew for x86_64 architecture. The resolution was to install homebrew natively for arm64 and subsequently install GCC.

```
gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin22/12/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-apple-darwin22
```